# Add additional files to Grails WAR file

Tags: grails, gradle

I wanna add additional files, respectively test data file, to the generated WAR file. How can I modify the build.gradle to reach this goal? I have already tried to change the war task, e.g.

```
war {
   from "testdata"
}
```

but no files were added to the war file. GRAILS 3.1.8 is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is example code - we use it to copy generated docs to war:

```
//copy documnetation to war if exist
war {
    from('build/docs/manual') {
        include '**/*'
        into('docs')
    }
}
```

Comment: Files are copied in the beginning during gradle configuration phase as well as during war task. How to make it run only during war task?